# trying to compare the latitude and longitude of the user's to the one in the database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, geolocation

so i want to create a system where we get the users latitude and longitude and compare it with the ones in the MySQL database to know if the users are located in those location or not. i managed to get the user's latitude and longitude but i would like a function to compare them with the ones i stored in my database. these are the code i used to get the location in my control

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Stevebauman\Location\Facades\Location;

class HealthController extends Controller
{
     public function showHealth(Request $request)
        {
        $ip = $request->ip;
        $data = Location::get($ip);

        return view ('healthcode',compact('data'));
        }
}
```

and this is my migration table:

```
 {
        Schema::create('healthcode', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('place');
            $table->string('latitude')->nullable();
            $table->string('longitude')->nullable();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check by searching in the DB like

```
Healthcode::where('latitude' => $data['latitude'])
    ->where('longitude' => $data['longitude'])
    ->exists();
```

Comment: this function is to fetch the coordinates from the database but not to compare them with the user's coordinates

Comment: if you can provide me a function to compare those that will be amazing thank you